# Troubleshooting installing Gherkin 2.1.5

Tags: ruby, linux, rubygems, gherkin

I am trying to install Gherkin 2.1.5, well, actually it is a dependency of https://github.com/opencongress/opencongress. I am using `bundle install` in the root directory of the code to install, about 20-30 packages got installed and now I'm stuck on this. I am running:

```
Linux 3.2.0-27-generic #43-Ubuntu SMP
Linux Mint 13 Maya
```

Here is the output once it stopped installing.

```
---snip--(a bunch of usings)
Installing gherkin (2.1.5) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lc... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/x86_64-linux -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -g -O2  -fPIC  -O0 -Wall -Werror  -c     gherkin_lexer_ar.c
/Users/aslakhellesoy/scm/gherkin/tasks/../ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl: In function ‘CLexer_scan’:
/Users/aslakhellesoy/scm/gherkin/tasks/../ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl:198:29: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘raise_lexer_error’     will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
/Users/aslakhellesoy/scm/gherkin/tasks/../ragel/i18n/ar.c.rl:198:29: error: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘raise_lexer_error’     will never be NULL [-Werror=address]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [gherkin_lexer_ar.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.1.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/gherkin-2.1.5/ext/gherkin_lexer_ar/gem_make.out
```

I have never programmed in ruby before so I am quite a bit out of touch with the whole install process of things. I had just figured out how to get redcloth to install and thought I was in the good. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`gem install gherkin -v '2.1.5' -- --with-cflags=-w`

did the trick for me.

Comment: This worked, but why?  Without understanding, we are consigned to browse stackoverflow forever!