# Installing Teambox on Ubuntu. Failing on Gherkin 2.3.3 installation

Tags: ubuntu, bundle, gherkin

I haven't found Teambox's support forum so I'm asking here. Note that I am completely new to Linux and its commandline syntax so please understand. :)

Anyway, I followed [this](https://github.com/teambox/teambox/wiki/Installing-locally) guide and managed to install all the prerequisites needed. After cloning the Git repository, I invoked the command:

```
bundle install
```

The script proceeded to install different apps but it stopped with a GCC compile error when installing Gherkin 2.3.3.

Is there any way to tell the "bundle" to "install" the latest gherkin instead of 2.3.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Bundle to pass the "ignore warning as error" parameter to the GEM. To do this, execute the following command before calling `bundle install`:

`bundle config build.gherkin --with-cflags=-w`

If that won't work, try this:

`bundle config gherkin --with-cflags=-w`

Reading this two SO entries helped me solve the problem:

[Troubleshooting installing Gherkin 2.1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188288/troubleshooting-installing-gherkin-2-1-5?rq=1)

[How can I pass a parameter for gem installation when I run bundle install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167829/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-for-gem-installation-when-i-run-bundle-install)